# Работа со множеством строк

Tags: c++, алгоритм

### Задача:

Дана строка, длиной не более 200000 символов. Нужно вывести все подстроки (подряд идущая последовательность символов внутри этой строки) используя множество.

### Моя логика решения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    char s[200001] = {};
    set <char*> mySet;
    cin >> s;
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        for (int j = 1; j <= len - i; ++j) {
            char s1[200001] = {};
            strncpy(s1, s + i, j);
            mySet.insert(s1);
        }
    copy(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), ostream_iterator<char*>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

### Проблема:

В множество заносится только 1 элемент (вроде бы только первая подстрока, т.е. 'a')

### Ввод:

abba

### Вывод:

a

### Должно вывести:

a ab abb abba b bb bba ba

Comment: ок, а вопрос в чем? пофиксить падение, уложится в время/память?

Comment: `200000` и в квадрат... вы представляете объём памяти? 40 гигабайт или я ошибся?

Comment: Не понимаю в чём проблема, почему во множество заносится только один элемент

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично, что ничего "не работает". У Вас множество не строк (как кажется на первый взгляд), а указателей. И заносится туда всегда только один и тот же указатель s1. То, что туда каждый раз копируются разные строки - ну бывает. Сам то указатель не меняется. Поэтому, в set всегда либо ноль, либо один указатель. Какая строка последняя осталась - та и будет.

"легкое переписывания" на более с++ код сразу решает все пробелемы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string s;
    set <string> mySet;
    cin >> s;
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        for (int j = 1; j <= len - i; ++j) {
            string s1 = s.substr(i,j);
            mySet.insert(s1);
        }
    for (auto x:mySet) { cout << x  << " ";}
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы выделяете на стеке здоровенные массивы - это не есть хорошо. Но главное, что вы сохраняете в сете указатель на размещенный на стеке массив `mySet.insert(s1)`
. После каждой итерации указатаель становится невалидным, так как массив на стеке выходит из области видимости и вы получаете неопределенное поведение. Рискну предположить что на каждой следующей итерации добавляемый указатель будет указывать на ту же самую область стека и новые данные просто не добавляются.

Используйте `std::string` вместо сырых массивов. Или допустим `std::string` совместно со `string_view`.